# Checking User Agent and regenerating session id in Session Class

Tags: php, mysql, security, session, pdo

I have written a class to store sessions in a database. I am stuck as to whether my checking of the user agent will work, as I cannot think of a way to test it.

I am also concerned that session_regenerate_id() is being called on every session_start() and am confused by the [manual's warnings regarding object destruction and the need for session_register_shutdown()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php#refsect1-function.session-set-save-handler-notes).

Will my user agent check always match?

Where is a better place for regenerating the session id?

Is the constructor a good place for session_register_shutdown()?

Thanks in advance.

The code:

Session.class.php

```
<?php
namespace Company\Project;

use \PDO;


class Session
{
    private $dblayer;
    private $user_agent;

    /**
     * Session constructor.
     * @param PDO $dblayer
     */
    public function __construct(PDO $dblayer)
    {
        $this->dblayer = $dblayer;
        $this->user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        session_set_save_handler(
            array($this, 'open'),
            array($this, 'close'),
            array($this, 'read'),
            array($this, 'write'),
            array($this, 'destroy'),
            array($this, 'gc')
        );

        if ('LIVE' == DEVELOPMENT_MODE) {
            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', true, true);
        } else {
            session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '', false, true);
        }

        session_register_shutdown();
        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id(true);

    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function open()
    {
        if ($this->dblayer) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function close()
    {
        $this->dblayer = null;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return bool|string
     */
    public function read($id)
    {
        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("SELECT data, user_agent FROM sessions WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

            if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $data =  $row['data'];
                $original_user_agent = $row['user_agent'];
            }

            if ($original_user_agent != $this->user_agent) {
                session_destroy();
                header('Location:' . SITE_PATH . '/login.php');
                exit;
            }

            return $data;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // will use file_put_contents to save error message, file etc to error log
            return '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @param $data
     * @return bool
     */
    public function write($id, $data)
    {
            $access = time();
            $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES(:id, :data, :user_agent, :access)");
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $stmt->bindParam(':data', $data);
            $stmt->bindParam(':user_agent', $user_agent);
            $stmt->bindParam(':access', $access);
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

            if ($stmt) {
                return true;
            }
            echo 'error';
            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // can i save to error log here?
            return false;

    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     * @return bool
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE id = :id");
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->dblayer->commit();

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // again, will save error data to log
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $max
     * @return bool
     */
    public function gc($max)
    {
        $to_delete = time() - $max;

        try {
            $this->dblayer->beginTransaction();
            $stmt = $this->dblayer->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE access < :to_delete");
            $stmt->bindParam(':to_delete', $to_delete);

            $this->dblayer->commit();

            return true;

        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            $this->dblayer->rollBack();
            // save error data to log;
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: "I am stuck as to whether my checking of the user agent will work"  Do you mean `if ($original_user_agent != $this->user_agent) {`?  If so, what about that check worries you?

Comment: Hi, sorry no I'm concerned about when the actions happen, and whether updating the database in the write method will mean the value will always match the value stored as a property of the object. I'm not really sure EXACTLY when the methods are called.

Comment: The description of the parameters in the [session_set_save_handler() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) should give you some insight.

Comment: I've read that page many times but am still confused. For example, "the write method is called when the session needs to be saved and closed" - but write to me means when you are setting a session variable?

Comment: When you set a session variable it's stored to the session. That session exists in memory, if you don't call `session_write_close()` it will never get written. This is the case whether you use built-in session handling or an external handler.

Comment: If this code is working, it's not well suited for this site. Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RyanVincent - shared hosting

Comment: @RyanVincent - my understanding is that by storing these sessions in my own database, not the filesystem which I have no control over security wise, is more secure as only my site has access to it.

Comment: How about storing the user agent in the _SESSION data when user logs in, then comparing with the value stored in _SERVER on every page load. Seems like you're mixing your login logic with your session handling stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three questions here (at least):

### Testing your User Agent check

To test, you can change your browsers User Agent; in Safari, there are a few options available in the Debug menu, Chrome and Firefox may have similar, or config options, but definitely have plugins to do this.

*However*, I would recommend against this type of checking (basic fingerprinting) — there are no guarantees that the user agent will not change — what happens if their browser installs an update mid-session? Frankly, if you can take over a users session, especially with the regeneration of session of IDs, you can spoof the users user agent.

### Regenerating Session IDs in constructor

While this is fine, at high load it may have a performance impact — a better option if you can is to only regenerate session IDs when you have an escalation of privileges, for example:

- On login
- When accessing user profile page
- When changing password
- When creating new content
- When checking out
- When logging out

### Using `session_register_shutdown();` in constructor

While the manual says that it's better to use `session_register_shutdown();` (or `register_shutdown_function('session_write_close')` in older versions) I actually disagree with this. It is possible to register multiple shutdown functions and they will be called in the order added with `register_shutdown_function()` — however, if one of them calls `exit` then no more are called.

I think it's better to call `session_write_close()` in your destructor instead,

```php
class Session
{
    … 

    public function __destruct()
    {
         session_write_close();
    }
}
```

This will get called even on after `exit` is called, when the stack is unraveled.

Comment: Be careful when relying on the `__destruct()` method for functions that should be called during shutdown can be dangerous. If the `register_shutdown_function` (or similar) is used when dealing with database connections etc. and an error occurs, the destruct method is never called and the database connection remains open. This is why critical shutdown functions should be registered in the constructor. Depending on how your sessions (database connections etc.) are managed this can be a serious concern.

Comment: This is actually a tough call for me. You can either use `register_shutdown_function()` which is _always_ called, so long as nothing in the chain calls `exit`, in which case subsequent functions are **never** called. However, use an object destructor won't work if a fatal error occurs (< PHP 7). Given that with PHP 7, destructors will be called on fatal errors now, I'd still go with that option.